# Django Change Date Format from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: python, django, date, date-format

I'm trying to pass input from a template to a query in my view, but if the date is not passed in Django's default date format YYYY-MM-DD then it throws an error.

**[u"'11/11/2012' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]**

***template.html***

```
<form method="GET" action="/BusComm/interactions">
    <div style="width: 100px; float:left">
        <p>To Date:</p>
    </div> 
    <div style="width: 200px; float:left">
        <input type="date" Placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" name="date_to" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}" float="right">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

***View.py***

```
 def interactions(request):
    today = datetime.now().date()
    table = interactionsTable(Interactions.objects.all())

    if request.GET.get('date_from'):
            date_from = request.GET.get('date_from')

            table = interactionsTable(Interactions.objects.filter(date__range=[date_from, today]))
            return render(request, 'BusComm/interactions.html',{
            'table': table,
        })
```

The **interactionsTable(Interactions.object.filter())** line is the one that throws the error.

My question is how can I change the date format in Django to accept MM/DD/YYYY instead of YYYY-DD-MM?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime('11/11/2012', '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> d.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
'2012/11/11'
```

Convert datetime format to `YYYY-DD-MM` in `views.py` is easier than force Django accept `MM/DD/YYYY` in filter.